# Cannot compile when move to another compose function

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Hi I don't know how can I call "weight(1f)" in my another comopose funtion

Error gives me

> Expression weight cannot be invoke as a function. The funtcion invokle is not found

FoodMenu

```
@Composable
fun FoodMenu(modifier: Modifier = Modifier)
{
 Row (modifier=Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
.wrapContentSize()
    )
  {
     FoodItem()
  }
}
```

FoodItem

```
@Composable
fun FoodItem(modifier: Modifier = Modifier)
{
   Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
   {
       Text(text= "Salad")
   }

   Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
   {
       Text(text= "Salad")
   }

}
```

Any help please,.thanks so much

Comment: You are missing closing brackets.

Comment: This has nothing to do with java; tag removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put Rowscope and it work

```
@Composable
fun RowScope.FoodItem(modifier: Modifier = Modifier)
{
   Box(
modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
       Text(text= "Salad")
   }

   Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
   {
       Text(text= "Fries")
   }
```